# App is not getting deployed

Tags: java, android

I've started coding in android. While running my app, I'm getting message "Unfortunately, myapp is stopped".
I've attached the code below.

Can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

The code is given below :

```
     package in.developer.rjsharma.myfirstapp;

     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.text.Editable;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             EditText fno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fno);

             String no1=fno.getText().toString();
             int first=Integer.parseInt(no1);


             EditText sno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sno);

             String no2=fno.getText().toString();
             int second=Integer.parseInt(no2);

             final int r1=first+second;

             final int r2=first-second;

             final int r3=first*second;

             final int r4=first/second;

             Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

             Button subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract);

             Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);

             Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

             final TextView solution = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution);

             add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     solution.setText(r1);
                 }
         });

             subtract.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     solution.setText(r2);
                 }
             });

             multiply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     solution.setText(r3);
                 }
             });

             divide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     solution.setText(r4);
                 }
             });


         }

     }
```

Comment: `Can you tell me what's wrong with this code?` Not without logcat.

Comment: You should include any messages you see in the LogCat and your layout xml also.  The most likely problem is that one of those findViewById calls is returning null (ie it can't find the view you are looking for), then you try to call a method on null.

Comment: `Can you tell me what's wrong with this code?` Have you debbuged ? Have you checked where (line) the error occurs ? What Error was raised ? What does the screen look like ? I am suprised you are not getting downvoted to hell. Questions like these are not welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to set `Integer` in `Textview`. You have to convert `Integer` to `String`

```
package in.developer.rjsharma.myfirstapp;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText fno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fno);

        String no1=fno.getText().toString();
        int first=Integer.parseInt(no1);

        EditText sno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sno);

        String no2=fno.getText().toString();
        int second=Integer.parseInt(no2);

        final int r1=first+second;
        final int r2=first-second;
        final int r3=first*second;
        final int r4=first/second;

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract);
        Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

        final TextView solution = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution);

        add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(r1));
            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(r2));
            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(r3));
            }
        });

        divide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                solution.setText(String.valueOf(r4));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making some mistakes in the code. You are reading the values of `EditText fno` in the `onCreate()`, it has just been created, their value would be an empty `String`. If you parse that to a value, I don't know if it will be `0` or `null`.

However, I would try it this way (not tested - likely to be errors with `solution` or other variables):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText fno, sno;
    private TextView solution;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText fno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fno);
        EditText sno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sno);

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract);
        Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

        TextView solution = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution);

        add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                solution.setText(readIntegerFromEditText(fno)+readIntegerFromEditText(sno));
            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                solution.setText(readIntegerFromEditText(fno)-readIntegerFromEditText(sno));
            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                solution.setText(readIntegerFromEditText(fno)*readIntegerFromEditText(sno));
            }
        });

        divide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                solution.setText(readIntegerFromEditText(fno)/readIntegerFromEditText(sno));
            }
        });
    } 

    private int readIntegerFromEditText (EditText editText){
        int no = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText());
        return no;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of things to be done yet, like checking for 0 division. You will find out on the way, if you use the LogCat and Debugging messages.